# Assignment Operators and Equality Operators

Tags: .net, vb6

In the C programming language, "DO TASK" always runs because a is assigned the value 1, rather than compared to the value 1:

```
    int a;
    a=0;
   if (a=1)
   {
       //DO TASK
   }
```

I am trying to figure out how this works in VB6 and .NET.  The following article suggests that the equality operator in .NET is '=' and not '==': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx.

What is the equality operator in VB6 and VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `=` is the equality operator in VB6 and VB.Net.

Can I respectfully suggest that you read the documentation? Trial and error is a very slow way to learn a language.  Here's the VB6 documentation

- [VB6 `=` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242760%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [VB6 assignment statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243390%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, '=' is the equality operator in Visual Basic 6 and Visual Basic .NET. It is also the assignment operator.

Comment: I have discovered this article, which clarifies it for VB6: http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-if-statements-and-conditionals-vb6

Comment: And things like this are a good reason why you better stay away from BASIC languages and use e.g. C# instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - is this particular issue really likely to cause problems for a competent programmer once they're familiar with Visual Basic?

Comment: For example, you  cannot do things like `if((foo = bar()) != null)`; and things like `foo = (bar == foobar)` would be extremely ugly or not possible at all.

Comment: Re the second example: `foo = bar = foobar` works just fine in Visual Basic .Net. Confusing for C programmers new to Visual Basic? Sure. Confusing to a competent VB.NET programmer (feel free to make jokes, everyone)? No.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The first example becomes foo = bar() : If foo Is Nothing Then.  So it's two statements. Is that really a big deal?

Comment: If it'd be part of an `elseif` block then yes, it is.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I think you are clutching at straws, as a senior programmer I would fail a program in code review if it contained a statement such as you first example. It is too open to misunderstanding during future maintenance of the program. Some people prefer C others VB, they are much of muchness these days in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes = is for VB 6 and VB.NET and == is for C# in .NET languages.

For .NET, you can also overload the equality operator, available here, in case you want to customize the process of equality: http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/08/30/introduction-to-operator-overloading-in-vbnet/